# Удаление с базы по userID (SEQUELIZE)

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

Всем привет, я не могу понять как делитнуть ключ от сообщения,
т.е удаление по кнопке,как ? ХЗ..

```
bot.action('allkeysuser', async (ctx) => {
await ctx.deleteMessage(ctx.update.callback_query.message.message_id);
const fromId = ctx.from.id
const mekeysus = await UserKEYs.findAll({where: {userID: fromId}})
const delkeysus = await UserKEYs.destroy({where: {userID: fromId, namekey: `${mekeysus.namekey}`}})

mekeysus.forEach(mekeysus => {
    ctx.reply(`Ключ: <code>${mekeysus.ukey}</code>\nНазвание: <code>${mekeysus.namekey}</code>`, 
    {
        parse_mode: 'HTML',
        ...Markup.inlineKeyboard(
            [
                Markup.button.callback('Удалить ключ', `${delkeysus.nam}`)
            ]
        )
    })
})
}
```

)

Comment: если что, ${delkeysus.namekey} не помогает

Comment: destroy разве не от инстанса вызывается?

Comment: не обязательно, вроде